# Can't ssh remotely, but can locally, after installing desktop on remote server

Tags: 18.04, ssh, sshd

I installed LXQT on my Digital Ocean Ubuntu 18.04 VM. Afterward, I could not ssh in remotely. I tried restarting the ssh service using the DO console. That did not work. So I completely uninstalled and purged LXQT and restarted. I also manually restarted `sshd`. I still cannot log in remotely.

However, I can `ssh` to `localhost` in the console.

I'm having trouble diagnosing because the `|` character maps to `>` in the console even if I cut and paste.

Comment: How about start sshd manually with the -d to get more verbose debug output?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to port forward your Local Lan Host IP.

Just open your modem's (or router's) interface through your browser using Default Gateway IP.

1. Look for "Port Forward" in the menu and enter that page. Look for a field labeled like "Local Lan Host Ip". Enter your Local Server's IP.
2. The default port for SSH client connections is 22. Enter 22 in all input fields labeled as something like "WAN Start Port" and "LAN Host Start Port".

You are done.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies? Before the issue I simply ssh from my terminal. Now I can't to the server in question. I can still ssh to all of my other servers. Why would I want to do anything with my modem or router?

Comment: You can SSH using localhost. Are you sure the IP of the server is set ok and not conflicted? run # ip addr show

Comment: You said you want to have access remotely and that locally it works. By remotely I assumed that you want to access server through WAN which can't be achieved without forwarding your Local IP to your ISP's IP

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. On the remote console provided by DO I can do `ssh localhost` suggesting that `sshd` was running. However, I cannot ssh from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be tracking the log files for the sshd. That would be the key to understand the problem.

The default log settings for sshd are `INFO`.
You need to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change the "LogLevel" from `INFO` to `VERBOSE`, or to use the trick from my comment.

After that, restart the `rsyslog` daemon to get the logs.

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

The ssh login attempts will be logged into the `/var/log/auth.log` where you should expect to see the problem.